# Kubernetes Handling a Sudden Request of Processing Power (Such as a Python Script using 5 Processes)

Tags: kubernetes

I have a little scenario that I am running in my mind with the following setup:

- A Django Web Server running in Kubernetes with the ability to autoscale resources (Google Kubernetes Engine), and I set the resource values to be requesting nodes with 8 Processing Units (8 Cores) and 16 GB Ram.

Because it is a web server, I have my frontend that can call a Python script that executes with 5 Processes, and here's what I am worried about:

- I know that If I run this script twice on my webserver (located in the same container as my Django code), I am going to be using (to keep it simple) 10 Processes/CPUs to execute this code.

So what would happen?

- Would the first Python script be ran on Pod 1 and the second Python script (since we used 5 out of the 8 processing units) trigger a Pod 2 and another Node, then run on that new replica with full access to 5 new processes?
- Or, would the first Python script be ran on Replica 1, and then the second Python script be throttled to 3 processing units because, perhaps, Kubernetes is allocating based on CPU usage in the Replica, not how much processes I called the script with?

Comment: When you say "a Python script with 5 processes", specifically in a Kubernetes process, how are you launching it?  Is it a subprocess in the Web server pod, or a separate (set of) Deployment(s), or something like a Celery worker, or something else?

Comment: @DavidMaze Hey - sorry, I should have clarified this. It is in the same container as my Django Webserver/pods. So essentially, in one of my Django views, a function that uses 5 CPUs/Processes is executed. This is my first Kubernetes question, so if something is still unclear, I'll make any effort to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

If your system has a Django application that launches scripts with `subprocess` or a similar mechanism, those will always be in the same container as the main server, in the same pod, on the same node.  You'll never trigger any of the Kubernetes autoscaling capabilities.  If the pod has resource limits set, you could get CPU utilization throttled, and if you exceed the configured memory limit, the pod could get killed off (with Django and all of its subprocesses together).

If you want to take better advantage of Kubernetes scheduling and resource management, you may need to restructure this application.  Ideally you could run the Django server and each of the supporting tasks in a separate pod.  You would then need a way to trigger the tasks and collect the results.

I'd generally build this by introducing a job queue system such as RabbitMQ or Celery into the mix.  The Django application adds items to the queue, but doesn't directly do the work itself.  Then you have a worker for each of the processes that reads the queue and does work.  This is not directly tied to Kubernetes, and you could run this setup with a RabbitMQ or Redis installation and a local virtual environment.

If you deploy this setup to Kubernetes, then each of the tasks can run in its own deployment, fed by the work queue.  Each task could run up to its own configured memory and CPU limits, and they could run on different nodes.  With a little extra work you can connect a horizontal pod autoscaler to scale the workers based on the length of the job queue, so if you're running behind processing one of the tasks, the HPA can cause more workers to get launched, which will create more pods, which can potentially allocate more nodes.

The important detail here, though, is that a *pod* is the key unit of scaling; if all of your work stays within a single pod then you'll never trigger the horizontal pod autoscaler or the cluster autoscaler.

Comment: Hi David, this is wonderful: I actually have a Natural Language Processing function from Gensim that uses multiple workers (LDA Model you can find here: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamulticore.html)

My current idea of the App would be that the Django application would hit the CPU utilization/memory limit, and then it would get horizontally scaled. Just like Celery (which I plan to have set up), when it needs more workers, more nodes are created. 

I'm a little unclear as to why the Celery example wouldn't work with Django - in which more nodes would be created from GKE?

Comment: Maybe I am understanding Horizontal Scaling wrong: I thought that it was by how close to the CPU/Memory limit we are reaching, we create a new pod and potentially a node. I am reading on your Celery example, and you have to feed the metric into Kubernetes - and naturally, I could be wrong with the Django pods too. Do I need to go about giving a metric to Kubernetes to scale the Django pods too?

Comment: In your current layout you could attach an HPA to your single Deployment and have it scale on CPU utilization.  It's a very reactive process, though: if you receive two requests that each kick off a 500%-CPU job, a minute or two later the HPA will notice that the deployment's average CPU is high and create another pod, and a minute or so later the _next_ request _could_ get routed to the new, less-busy pod.  Similarly, if the HPA scales down, it could decide to shut down a pod that's still doing work.  The job-queue system would be able to retry jobs in this case.

Comment: Ok - then I have a problem I don't know how to solve. The Gensim process I showed you, I desire to run it on, say, 5 vCPU. Celery only runs each of it's workers using 1 CPU. I can't use something like Dask, so I'm stuck: I don't know what to do if I want to run a CPU intensive task that doesn't have a native integration with a scheduler. Going back to the points you made, I would run each Django with a limit higher than the max workers I specify to use - rather than limiting to 1 CPU and autoscaling from there. I really appreciate you helping me out here.

Comment: Also, what stopping the same series of failures from happening to the Django pods themselves. Given your approach, the same could happen which something is schedule to a less busy pod that is scaled down - how could I ever prevent that?